# How the "Quickplay finish" article works on a rook vs rook or rook vs minor piece endgame?

Tags: time-control, rook-endgame, claim-draw, arbiters, rook-and-minor-endgame

Suppose 2 players are playing in a 10-10 or blitz format with no increment. In the endgame the players are left with only rook vs a piece (rook / bishop / knight nearer to king) or similar drawing-game material but no pawns.

Now the one who is ahead on clock decides to play, to let the opponent exhaust on time who is around 2 minutes. (This often happens where a player gets flagged in chess.com.)

**Questions**:

Can the losing player invoke the [Article 10.2](https://www.fide.com/FIDE/handbook/LawsOfChess.pdf) to arbiter for claiming a draw?

> 10.2. If the player has less than two minutes left on his clock, he may claim a draw before his flag falls. He shall stop the clocks and summon the arbiter.
>
> (a) If the arbiter is satisfied the opponent is making no effort to win the game by normal means, or that it is not possible to win by normal means, then he shall declare the game drawn. Otherwise he shall postpone his decision.
>
> (b) If the arbiter postpones his decision, the opponent may be awarded two extra minutes thinking time and the game shall continue in the presence of the arbiter.
>
> (c) Having postponed his decision, the arbiter may subsequently declare the game drawn, even after a flag has fallen.

Answer (score 3):

> Can the losing player invoke the Article 10.2 to arbiter for claiming a draw?

According to the current [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023) 10.2 says this:

> **Article 10: Points**
> ...
> 10.2   The total score of any game can never exceed the maximum score normally given for that game. Scores given to an individual player must be those normally associated with the game, for example a score of ¾ - ¼ is not allowed.

The part that you want to invoke comes in Guidelines III. Here are the relevant parts:

> **Guidelines III. Games without Increment including Quickplay Finishes**

III.1    A ‘quickplay finish’ is the phase of a game when all the remaining moves must be completed in a finite time.

> III.2.1     **The Guidelines below concerning the final period of the game including Quickplay Finishes, shall only be used at an event if their use has been announced beforehand.**
>
> III.2.2     **These Guidelines shall apply only to standard chess and rapid chess games without increment and not to blitz games**.

These rules apply only in standard and rapid tournaments where there has been an announcement beforehand that these rules apply. So, no, these rules do not apply in your case.

Comment: The last part of the answer is not clear. III.2.2 says *standard & rapid* and then you write *standard & blitz*. Also what about the FIDE article 10.2? I couldn't find any mention of before-hand announcement about "quick play finish". Doesn't it mean that, in any situation the player can call an arbiter to claim a draw if the endgame is rook vs rook?

Comment: @iammilind Thanks! I've corrected that typo. FIDE article 10.2 is not currently what you quoted. You are looking at a very old version from 10 or more years ago. In a rook vs rook endgame a player can only call the arbiter to claim a draw if 1) the player has less than 2 minutes on the clock 2) it is standard or rapid with no increment and 3) It was announced beforehand that Guidelines III would apply.

Comment: Any old chessplayer knows the infamous "10.2", but this refers to an old version of the rules. The article more or less just moved. The idea, of course, is that this article places too much work on the arbiter (especially the arbiter should be a strong player) which should be avoided, and the moved 10.2 should apply in as few cases as possible. (E.g. increment rules it out completely.)